# iterating ssh-copy-id command to copy on multiple hosts

Tags: linux, loops, automation, expect, ssh-keys

I am trying to copy public key to my multiple hosts in a file called "hostsfile".
I am writing a script that will allow me to do that as I am setting a dev environment and I may end up doing it over and over.
Googling around I have been able to place insert the public key using ssh-copy-id command and have been able to automate it for one host.
However the code needs to be fine tuned to go through each and every host in the hostsfile...unfortunately it completes the first entry and then exits:
Below is the code... Appreciate any help in advance....

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10
set f [open "hostsfile"]
set hosts [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

set exp_internal 1
foreach host $hosts {
    spawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/vagrant/.ssh/ansible-use-ssh-key.pub $host
    expect_after eof { exit 0 }
    expect "password:" { send "vagrant\r" }
    expect_after eof { exit 0 }
    expect "$ "
    }
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Glen this is what I made out of your comments.... Can you advise please and if you dont mind help with the complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10
set f [open "hostsfile"]
close $f

set hosts [split [read -nonewline $f] "\n"]

foreach host $hosts {
    spawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/vagrant/.ssh/ansible-use-ssh-key.pub $host
    expect "password:" 
    send "vagrant\r"
    expect eof
}
puts done
```

Hi Glen it worked with the following code as you suggested. However if the key already exists on one of the hosts the process terminates. can you suggest how i can add if/else state for it to not break if the remote host responds with key already exists? Thanks for your help in advance.

Below is the code that worked for the first problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10
set f [open "hostsfile"]
set hosts [split [read -nonewline $f] "\n"]
close $f


foreach host $hosts {
    spawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/vagrant/.ssh/ansible-use-ssh-key.pub $host
    expect "password:"
    send "vagrant\r"
    expect eof
}
```

puts done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have instructed expect to exit after eof. Don't do that.

```
foreach host $hosts {
    spawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/vagrant/.ssh/ansible-use-ssh-key.pub $host
    expect "password:" 
    send "vagrant\r"
    expect eof
}
puts done
```

Note that your $hosts list has an empty last element. Use `read -nonewline` to read the file:

```
set hosts [split [read -nonewline $f] "\n"]
```

Comment: thank you glenn, however i am getting the following error now: "can not find channel named "file6"
    while executing
"read -nonewline $f"
    invoked from within
"split [read -nonewline $f] "\n""
    invoked from within
"set hosts [split [read -nonewline $f] "\n"]"
    (file "./ssh-copy_F.sh" line 6)

Comment: You were meant to replace the current split-read line, not add a new line after you've already closed the file.

Comment: Ok I think I found the mistake... i switched the close and set host lines... However now am facing another issue that is if the key already exists on one of the hosts its terminating the whole script... So how would i add that into the script?  Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Glen, I found the answer to my second question... Below is the code that is apparently working for me. Thank you for the kind help and getting me through that.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10
set f [open "hostsfile"]
set hosts [split [read -nonewline $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach host $hosts {
    spawn ssh-copy-id -i /home/vagrant/.ssh/ansible-use-ssh-key.pub $host
    expect {
            "password:" {
                    send "vagrant\r"
                    exp_continue
                }
                "already exist on the remote system." {
                    exp_continue
                }
    expect eof
        }
}
puts done
```

Comment: Change `expect eof` to just `eof`